# How to list processes by real executable name?

Tags: macos, process-monitoring

Processes can update their "command" field at runtime, using the `setproctitle` method. This will alter how the process shows up in several commands:

```
$ ps 33933
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
33933 s000  S      0:00.52 spring server | todo-mvc | started 45 hours ago
```

However, `spring` is not an executable, this is actually a ruby script, so the output I'm looking for is `/Users/rpatterson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby`.

[This blog post](https://astojanov.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/mac-os-x-resolve-absolute-path-using-process-pid/) explains how you can get the real path using a seemingly-undocumented method `proc_pidpath`. Activity monitor also shows `ruby` correctly, which would be close enough for me to find and kill the related processes.

How can I get this information from the command line without compiling my own program?

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete answer that practically accomplishes my goal has been:

```
fuser $(which ruby) | xargs ps
```

This allows me to identify which processes started from a particular `ruby`, but can include false positives (for example, an attached debugger would also be listed).